# Opening and closing a hslogger log file, within the GHCi REPL

Tags: haskell, logging, io, ghci, filehandle

I am annoyed with my implementation of hslogger, when running within the GHCi REPL.

```
import System.IO (Handle)
import System.Log.Logger (Priority( DEBUG ), updateGlobalLogger, addHandler, setLevel, debugM)
import System.Log.Handler.Simple (fileHandler)
import System.Log.Handler (setFormatter, close)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    f <- fileHandler "sample.log" DEBUG
    updateGlobalLogger "Component" (addHandler f)
    updateGlobalLogger "Component" (setLevel DEBUG)
    debugM "Component" "This is a sample log line"
    close f
```

It runs without exception the first time, however, on subsequent executions of main:

```
*** Exception: sample.log: hPutStr: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

This is not experienced when I'm running the program outside of GHCi.

*Am I not closing the file handle correctly with hslogger, or does GHCi keep the file handle open?*

I don't the experience the same problem when opening and closing a standard file.

```
import System.IO (Handle, openFile, hClose, hPutStrLn, IOMode (WriteMode))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    f <- openFile "sampleFile.log" WriteMode
    hPutStrLn f "Hello"
    hClose f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `removeHandler` in conjunction with `close` seems to work:

```
import System.IO (Handle)
import System.Log.Logger (Priority( DEBUG ), updateGlobalLogger, addHandler, setLevel, debugM, removeHandler)
import System.Log.Handler.Simple (fileHandler)
import System.Log.Handler (setFormatter, close)

main1 :: FilePath -> IO ()
main1 fp = do
    f <- fileHandler fp DEBUG
    updateGlobalLogger "Component" (addHandler f)
    updateGlobalLogger "Component" (setLevel DEBUG)
    debugM "Component" ("This is a sample log line to file " ++ fp)
    updateGlobalLogger "Component" removeHandler
    close f

main = do main1 "foo.log"; main1 "foo.log"
```

Comment: Great. Now to properly clean up when exceptions arise.